# Statement is not being reached after setting State in react ES-6

Tags: reactjs, electron, es6-promise, fixed-data-table

In this react code i am trying to set the data to current state,After setting the data to state i need to use it in fixed data table.To achieve it, i wrote as below.The main issue is that the statement next to **"this.setState**" in **componentDidMount** is not being executed/reached where i need to call data table  function there.
here is my code:

```
     export default class Main extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                result: [],
                loading: false,
                filteredRows: null,
                filterBy: null,
            };
        }
        getZipData() {
            //Here i got the data from server 
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.getZipData().then((data)=>{
                console.log("data:"+data.length);
                this.setState({result:data,loading:true});  //state successfully set here.
                console.log("result:*******************"+this.state.result.length); //this console is not printed
this._filterRowsBy(this.state.filterBy)
            });

        };
        _rowGetter(rowIndex){
            alert("row Getter");
            return this.state.filteredRows[rowIndex];
        }
        _filterRowsBy(filterBy){
            var rows = this.state.result.slice();
            var filteredRows = filterBy ? rows.filter((row)=>{
                return row.RecNo.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.toLowerCase()) >= 0
            }) : rows;
            this.setState({
                filterRows,
                filterBy,
            })
        }
        _onFilterChange(e){
            this._filterRowsBy(e.target.value);
        }
        render() {
            if(this.state.loading==false) {
                return (
                    <div className="row-fluid">
                        <img className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3"
                             src="http://www.preciseleads.com/images/loading_animation.gif"/>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            else{
                console.log("result:////////////////////"+this.state.result.length); //this console is printed
                console.log("loading completed");
                return(
                    <div>
                       <!-- fixed data table code goes here -->
                    </div>
                )
            }

        }
    }
```

state is successfully updated but after that statement is not reached, IN **componentDidMount**,
any help much appreciated.

Comment: I don't suppose this is an electron specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add a catch handler to your Promise. I suppose you are getting an error.

Comment: yah then i got this Error: Invariant Violation: child typ
e should be <FixedDataTableColumn /> or <FixedDataTableColumnGroup />

Comment: So thats the problem. Solve it and all would work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there maybe this is your problem,

Facebook:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains. setState() will always trigger a
>   re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in
>   shouldComponentUpdate(). If mutable objects are being used and the
>   logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), calling
>   setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state
>   will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

```
  this.setState({result:data,loading:true}, () => {
    // Your logic
  });
```

the second argument is a callback function which is called after the state is set.

Hope this helps:)

Edit: i didn't see the invariant error, (From the comment, could u provide the full error)